# finding out which layout has an error

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using `<include layout>` in my android app and one of my included layout had an error, one parameter (`android:layout_height`) was not set.

the LogCat Error log gave a quite useless error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #19: you 
must supply a layout_height attribute
```

is there a simple way to find out, which layout was affected (**Binary XML-File** is really a wide definition)? i had to dig through all layouts to find the flawed XML-layout-file

i'm using Android Developer Tools v21.1 but though the error comes from logCat i'm not sure if there is a better way to find the flawed file...

Comment: Sorry, you **can** but don't have to have those attributes on an included layout.

Comment: @Martin Frank : Yes you do have to find it manually :)

Comment: @CharlesDurham the problem is not how to layout - the problem is, how to find the invalid file... depending on your **layout** and **sdk-version**, the parameter is **required**...

Comment: @AndiGeeky thanky you very much, don't destroy my hopes before chrismas! i hope someone might come up with an answer - but if not you can post an answer and i'll accept it next year (its not very long until then)

Comment: @Martin Frank : Hahaha.. There is `logs` at `Messages` tab of `Android studio` for invalid files.. I have used it so far.. May be it can help you.. :)

Comment: may it's time so switch IDE then, as mentioned above, post an answe and i'll accept it ^^ @AndiGeeky

Comment: @Martin Frank : Sure..please check answer..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #19: you 
must supply a layout_height attribute
```

As you have mentioned that you can switch to different IDE, I guess you are using **Eclise**. So it is time to install **Android Studio** for android development.

In fact Google has already stopped support for Android `plug-in` in **Eclipse**.

As shown in below image you can see logs for invalid file at **Messages** tab.

[image]

Hope your christmas will be great with this solution :-p

Comment: thank you very much! i know now what to wish from Uncle Crimbo =)  i hope he brings the newest version of **Android Studio** (great answer, even with pic, good job)

Comment: @ Martin Frank : Thank you..!!

Comment: hei - looks like this answer was really worth writing it ^_^